# Is there silent installation command without desktop shortcuts for QGIS?

Tags: qgis, installation, windows-7

I installed QGIS with Microsoft SCCM 2012 and I want to make a silent install without desktop shortcuts.

I managed to do a silent install with / S but I found no s command to delete desktop shortcuts.

I have Windows 7 64 client PCs.

Answer (score -1):

Although i believe that your question is rather a windows issue (how can i create/change desktop shortcuts), maybe until you solved that problem you can use a portable version of QGIS for your users. Under the following [link](http://ceg-sense.ncl.ac.uk/geoanorak/code/qgis18usb.html) you can download a full functional QGIS 1.8 version. It already comes with all mayor features and some plugins installed.
Extract it to a folder of your choice, add the folder location to the qgis.bat (in case it isn't starting) and execute it to start QGIS.